# iOS: How do I work around casting to const char with ARC enabled?

Tags: ios, casting, char, constants

I have this:

```
// Setup the SQL Statement and compile it for faster access
NSString *sqlStatement = @"SELECT * FROM nameList";

const char *sqlStatementC  = (const char* )sqlStatement;
```

But ARC does not like this. Is there a workaround?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
const char* sqlStatementC  = [sqlStatement cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

or

```
const char* sqlStatementC  = [sqlStatement UTF8String];
```

Comment: From the SO guidelines: "[...] you should accept the best answer, **or if there are equivalent ones, the first one**"

Comment: @graver Have I said yet that you rock?

Comment: @H2CO3 :) It's obvious that your answer should be accepted.. I even upvoted you first :)

Comment: Wow. That's really nice of you to say.

Answer (score 9):

Because this is absolutely invalid. sqlStatement is an `NSString`, an Objective-C object. You can't simply cast it to `const char *`. You have to use a method to access its contents as a C srting:

```
const char *sqlStatementC = [sqlStatement UTF8String];
```

Remark 1: by the way, this is completely unrelated to ARC.

Remark 2: use the pointer marker asterisk sticked to the variable name, not the type name (i. e. `const char* sqlStatementC` is not very good, `const char *sqlStatementC` is better).

Comment: @Pruitlgoe: it may be, but there's a reason writing it like this.

Comment: only if you're declaring multiple variables on the same line, a coding style which I don't like to do. Otherwise, the compiler sees the white space as irrelevant. Additionally, when writing a method, say -(NSString* ) myMethod : (NSString* ) aString you'll note the pointer reference is with the class name, not the variable. To me, that is a pretty good argument that the pointer should be closer to the class name than the variable name. But this is arguing over a moot point, as we both agree it is a style preference.

Comment: @PruitIgoe of course :) may I say I like the type *ident format?